# A synonym for "name"

Tags: word-request

I'm talking about a person's name. For example:

> He wanted to change his __ at the registation office.

I searched on [Google](https://www.google.com.tw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=synonym%20of%20name). But the results are kind of strange, and I'm not very sure if they are commonly used.

Comment: Could you maybe give us more context? It seems like "name" would do just fine for that example. What exactly was he trying to change? First name, last name?

Comment: [Relevant, but probably not a dupe](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62415/how-to-inform-other-people-of-your-real-name/62434#62434).

Comment: I can't see why you would want a different word. If you want something very informal, you could use the word **monicker**. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/monicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even though I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, consider these terms:

> **first name** (or less commonly **forename**) - if your full name is John Doe, your first name would be John
>   **given name** - if your full name is John Doe, your given name would be John because that's the name you were given by your parents when you were born.
>   **user name** - your user name on this website is alex.
>   **screen name** - pretty much the same thing as user name, but the only difference is that you hear this term more often used when, for example, calling a live TV show over the phone and they're going to use a screen name of your choosing instead of your real name to address you.

I guess **given name** would be the term you're looking for.

Comment: You missed "surname", "last name" and "Christian name"...

Comment: I've given enough information I think. The rest can be easily looked up in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

**"Identity"** - may be a possible word to replace **name, qualities, beliefs, personality, looks and/or expressions that make a person.** Especially if we are mentioning a passport or some other document.

**"cognomen"** - if we speak of a Latin word. See also **'nomen'**:

> Surname, any name, especially a nickname, the third and commonly the
>   last name of a citizen of ancient Rome, indicating the person's house
>   or family, as “Caesar” in “Gaius Julius Caesar.”.

But I still agree with most comments that **"name"** would perfectly fit.